# Google direction api not working correctly

Tags: java, google-maps

I am working on a java program where I use text search and directions api, but somehow api's are not working correctly in some cases.

For example: I have to search "restaurants" near `Hyundai Car Center,Sector 63, Noida`.

For this I have used the text search api to get the formatted address of the required restaurant.
Now when I used direction api to calculate the shortest time and distance between the locations, I did not find any result.

```
String addressFrom = "Mother Dairy, Bhim Nagri, Hauz Khas, New Delhi, India";
String addressTo = "Hyundai Car Center,Sector 63,Noida";
String urlString = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=true&origin="
                + addressFrom + "&destination=" + addressTo;
System.out.println(urlString);
```

I am getting the following output:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=true&origin=Mother+Dairy%2C+Bhim+Nagri%2C+Hauz+Khas%2C+New+Delhi%2C+India&destination=Hyundai+Car+Center%2CSector+63%2CNoida
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DirectionsResponse>
 <status>NOT_FOUND</status>
</DirectionsResponse>
```

Comment: You may want to use this small light library which parses everything for you: https://github.com/perezdidac/google-directions-api

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "Mother Dairy, Bhim Nagri, Hauz Khas, New Delhi, India" cannot be found. You can test whether the endpoints can be found by entering them (one at a time) in the [Google Geocoder Sample page](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple).

However, "Bhim Nagri, Hauz Khas, New Delhi, India" *can* be found, and is fairly close to where "Mother Dairy" is marked on the map.

Comment: i tried..but it was not able to geocode by using api.. but if we search on google map..we get the result. Also the address is the formatted address,then why it is not able to geocode. This prob is almost in every case

Comment: Google Maps (rather than geocoder API in the API maps) uses all of the various APIs to get results. You're attempting to geocode a **business,** not an address.

Comment: I din't get u.. Is there any way I could get the required result?

Comment: You could use the Places API to get the location of the business, and then use that location as the start point of the directions. The geocoder finds *street addresses*, not business names. That is it will find "35 Strand, London UK" but not "Mcdonalds, Strand, London UK".

Comment: The address "Mother Dairy, Bhim Nagri, Hauz Khas, New Delhi, India" is  the address which I have found through text search places API.
Actually I have to get an address from the text search api, and then I have to calculate distance and time between the the source addrs and the address returned from the place search api.

Comment: Exactly: you have used the Places API.

Comment: so what should I do..I have to do everything at runtime.

Comment: Well, you could use the Places API. But I don't know how that works in Java. Or you could advise that addresses need to be street addresses, not business names.

Comment: yes I ahve used the places api only .. It seems you are not getting my point. I will explain you clearly. I have got an formatted address from the place search Api.(Mother Dairy, Bhim Nagri, Hauz Khas, New Delhi, India). This address in streer address not "business" address. Then why I am not able to geocode it.

Comment: I will say again: **You need to use the Places API to get the location and pass that to the Directions API.** The Directions API uses the Geocoder, and that can't find the location you are giving it (for whatever reason: I've told you why though).